# How to setup AWS EC2 instance such that it accepts public traffic with specific cert

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, amazon-ec2

I want to run some web service on my AWS EC2 instance and visit it from my own laptop. I want it only be accessible by myself and I can visit it from anywhere (so my IP changes).

I'm wondering if there's some quick & neat certification solution for this. Ideally, I can install some kind of CERT on my laptop and the server gonna verify that and then it accepts all traffic.

Is there some open source solution for this?

Comment: You can use [SSM port forwarding](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-port-forwarding-using-aws-system-manager-sessions-manager/) to forward a port without opening the instance to any traffic.

Comment: @AnonCoward looks promising. Thanks!